# user-defined Sigmoid function in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

I have one doubt on using user-defined sigmoid function(Logistic). I tried using numpy.exp & math.exp for the sigmoid formula `(1 / 1+ e^-x)`.

```
1 / (1 + numpy.exp(-x))
1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))
```

Both methods gives the value 6.900207837141513e-36 for x = -80.96151181531121. 
But, we are expecting a value between 0  & 1.
Am I missing anything?

Comment: You're missing scientific notation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

6.900207837141513e-36 is scientific record for 0.00...06900207837141513 (I omitted 13 zeroes)

You can read it as "6.900... divided by 10^36". In this case you probably can treat value as 0.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> 6.900207837141513e-36 > 0
True
```

Comment: and `6.900207837141513e-36 < 1`

Answer (score 0):

Note the `e-36` on the end of `6.900207837141513e-36`. This is equivalent to the [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) `6.900207837141513 * 10^-36`. In other words, it is a very small value that is basically zero.